# Segmentation fault in C++ for array of structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting a segmentation fault in this code ? I was attempting to initialize an array of structures.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
        string data;
        int index;
        node(string data,int index):data(data),index(index){}
};
struct node **init_array(int n){
        struct node **array=(struct node **)malloc(n*sizeof(struct node *));
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                *(array+i)=NULL;
        return(array);
}
struct node *init_node(string data,int index){
        struct node *t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data=data;
        t->index=index;
        return(t);
}
int main(){
        node **array=init_array(5);
        *(array+0)=init_node("Debal",23);
        *(array+1)=init_node("Debdut",24);
        *(array+2)=init_node("Debojyoti",22);
        *(array+3)=init_node("Ditsa",29);
        *(array+4)=init_node("Divyani",10);
        cout << (*(array+3))->index;
}
```

I was expecting the structures to be initialized with NULL.

Comment: First learn more C++ (your code is a mix of "C" and "C++" now), using malloc for C++ classes is not good (undefined behavior).  Try rewriting your code using std::vector<node>. [struct](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-structs-members-and-member-selection/), [vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/). Stop using `using namespace std;`. Where are you learning C++ from, because it doesn't seem to be a good source .

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `malloc` on types which have constructors (like `std::string`) because `malloc` will not call those constructors. Use `new` instead.

```
node* init_node(string data, int index)
{
    node* t = new node(data, index);
    return t;
}
```

There really is no need to use malloc in a C++ program.

Comment: *there are possible uses of `std::malloc` in C++ but no real need to use it.